# Covariant derivative induced by a connection

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying Ralph Cohen's lecture notes on the topology of fiber bundles and encountered the following definition of covariant derivative induced by a connection on principal bundles: the covariant derivative induced by the connection $\omega_A$
\begin{equation}
  D_A: \Omega^0(M;ad(P)) \to \Omega^1(M;ad(P))
\end{equation}
is defined by
\begin{equation}
  D_A(\sigma)(X) = [\widetilde{X},\sigma]
\end{equation}
where $\sigma \in \Omega^0(M;ad(P))$, $X$ is a vector field on $M$, $\widetilde{X}$ its horizontal lifting from the tangent space of the base space $M$ to that of the total space $P$ via the connection $\omega_A$ as the connection defines a splitting.  But I am not sure what the bracket operation on the right-hand side refers to.  Could somebody help me to clarify it?  Many thanks!

Comment: Lie bracket perhaps?

Comment: I was thinking of that because the codomain of $\sigma$ is $\mathfrak{g}$.  But $\widetilde{X}$ is a vector field.

Comment: Well it must be the differential geometric Lie bracket of vector fields; he even mentions it right before this definition. However this acts on a smooth function $f$ as $\tilde{X}(\sigma(f))-\sigma(\tilde{X}(f))$, and I don't know how that can be defined properly. He mentions Spivak though in his references, maybe you can look it up there.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the pain to look up Cohen's notes, Pasternaak!  I really appreciate it!  I found the answer in Clifford Henry Taubes book on differential geometry (Oxford GTM023) pp.129 and am sharing it with you.  In fact the right-hand side is not a bracket operation at all!